# Drupal Webform calculating to Zero for paid event

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

Using CiviCRM 5.58.1 and Drupal 7.97
I have a field that calculates the total cost using conditionals in the webform: [subscriptions][civicrm_1_participant_1_participant_fee_amount]
(I also did try to take it out of the fieldset in case that was messing up the calculation. This did not change the result)

As far as I know, this form, before I began to edit it for current event and price changes, DID work. Now the "Continue to payment page" comes up **as zero**, except for any additional contribution entered by the user. (I had this problem recently on another CiviCRM site, and gave up and changed to using an event page instead of a webform.)

**How it looks to user:**

Subscriptions
Subscription series ordering *
2

Subscription series price *
x $150

Subscription Series Cost *
$300

*Above Subscription Series Cost is the `civicrm_1_participant_1_participant_fee_amount` field*

Additional tax deductible contribution
$

**Continue to payment page**

2023-2024 Subscription Series
**Total $ 0.000**

Above example should charge the user $300, not $0!!

Comment: Tend to agree with Lars that making a version of your form that is at its most simplest is a good way to see where it goes wrong. What you are wanting should be doable. We may need more detail. What versions of webform and w_c. Are you using webform_calculator? (You may need to do this if you are trying to do calculations). If you can strip it down to its simplest version, pref. with no custom fields on it, then you could node_export it so one of us could take a quick look.

Comment: also noting that where the page break happens can be important

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully someone who knows more about this might be able to give you a better answer. My experience (also on D7) has been that this is finicky and sometimes does not work, as you are experiencing. What has sometimes helped for me is to remove all these fields from the form by removing the participant and contribution from the CiviCRM tab and then re-adding them. It seems to also sometimes help to put everything on one page (and remove them all from fieldsets or put them all in the same fieldset). Probably there is something specific going wrong, but I've never been able to figure out exactly what it is.